# See Facebook Likes in Date Order

Tags: facebook, social-likes

Is there a way I can see the order in which people like my facebook page? I would like to identify the 5000th like to give them a prize.

Is this possible?

Stuart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because you can't access the list of ALL users which liked you page.

You can only access the likes of ONE user once he gave his `user_likes` permission to your app (if you have one).